# What is the the meaning of "…in what is delivered and implemented…"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I'm translating a book into Persian. Please help me understand the meaning of "in what is..." in bold below.

> But within the equivalence of equality there is a recognizable difference **in what is** delivered and implemented both interinstitutionally and intra-interinstitutionally.

Comment: there is a **difference in**

Answer (score 1):

'In what is delivered' = 'in the thing that is delivered'. The phrase refers to the substance/content of what is being delivered.